# Circles and tangents

Tags: geometry, circles

3 circles of radius **3 cm, 4cm, 5 cm** touch each other **externally** at $A$, $B$, $C$.
Tangents drawn at $A$, $B$, $C$ intersect at $P$.

Find $ PA  +   PB  +  PC$ .

Thanks.

**My thoughts and approach**:

Well I made the figure but still could not proceed ahead.

Comment: First hint: what can you say on the length of $PA$ compared to the length of $PB$?

Comment: I dont know , And I cant get any idea :(

Comment: Ok, let's start from another angle: what level of geometry do you know?

Comment: Thats a bit hard to explain but maybe relative to the standards of this site I dont know much.

Comment: This is not an answer. Do you know about equilateral triangles? Right triangles? Properties of tangent lines to circles? Anything?

Comment: Yes.Yes.Yes.Equations of circles,properties of triangles :).Sorry for the previous POST :(

Answer (score 1):

$PA+PB+PC$ is just three times the inradius of a triangle having side lengths $(a,b,c)=(7,8,9)$. Since
$$ r(a+b+c) = 2\Delta,$$
we only need to find the area of the triangle thorugh Heron's formula. We have:
$$\Delta^2 = p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c) = 12\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5,$$
hence $\Delta=12\sqrt{5}$ and:
$$PA+PB+PC = 3r=\frac{6\Delta}{a+b+c} = 3\sqrt{5}.$$